# Is there a way to pass variable to dangerouslySetInnerHTML in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How do I pass {currentyear} to label component?

```
let text = "<p><span>Year {currentyear}</span></p>";
<Label text={dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}}}
```

**Label**  is a component that takes in text as property  and displays it on the document

Comment: Obligatory: Do you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` here? If that is actual code and not just an example, it seems like you could just nest the labels content normally.

Comment: You said you are getting this string from the JSON response, but how do you expect to get your JS variable inside this JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a literal string:

```
"<p><span>Year {currentyear}</span></p>"
```

It sounds like you're looking for a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`<p><span>Year ${currentyear}</span></p>`
```

This will evaluate the `currentyear` variable into the resulting string when first setting the `text` variable.

---

**Edit:** In a comment below you indicate that this string value comes from an external source:

```
"<p><span>Year {currentyear}</span></p>"
```

Which means it's a string and can't be a template literal.  In that case you can simply perform your string replacement manually.  For example:

```
let text = yourString.replace('{currentyear}', currentyear);
```

---

The point of all of this is that it's not really a question of "using a variable in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`".  You're already doing that (using the `text` variable).  What you're trying to do is simply manipulate a string in JavaScript.  There is [a lot of string functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) you can use.

Comment: I'm getting that string from a JSON response.

Comment: @UthkarshCheekati: Can you clarify that in the question?  If there's information about the problem that you share piece-by-piece in response to answers then that's called a "moving target" and it makes answering very difficult.